# Configure/activate ECR enhanced scanning via AWS CDK

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I want to activate ECR enhanced scanning (continuous scanning) for an ECR registry via AWS CDK. I checked the API reference but the [AWS ECR ImageScanningConfigurationProperty](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecr.CfnRepository.ImageScanningConfigurationProperty.html) does not provide an enhanced scanning option. I checked aws-inspector v1 and v2 as well but was not able to find something. Any suggestions how to realize this in AWS CDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you definitely can do that with AWS CDK. Check out my sample below. Hope it helps!

```js
import {
  Stack,
  StackProps,
  aws_iam as iam,
  custom_resources as cr,
  ArnFormat
} from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import {
  Construct
} from 'constructs';
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

export class MyStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props ? : StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const onCreateParam: AWS.ECR.PutRegistryScanningConfigurationRequest = {
      scanType: 'ENHANCED',
      rules: [{
        repositoryFilters: [{
          filter: '*',
          filterType: 'WILDCARD',
        }, ],
        scanFrequency: 'SCAN_ON_PUSH',
      }]
    };
    const onDeleteParam: AWS.ECR.PutRegistryScanningConfigurationRequest = {
      scanType: 'BASIC',
      rules: [{
        repositoryFilters: [{
          filter: '*',
          filterType: 'WILDCARD',
        }, ],
        scanFrequency: 'SCAN_ON_PUSH',
      }]
    };

    const enabler = new cr.AwsCustomResource(this, 'EnhancedScanningEnabler', {
      policy: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromSdkCalls({
        resources: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.ANY_RESOURCE,
      }),
      onCreate: {
        service: 'ECR',
        physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of('id'),
        action: 'putRegistryScanningConfiguration',
        parameters: onCreateParam,
      },
      onDelete: {
        service: 'ECR',
        action: 'putRegistryScanningConfiguration',
        parameters: onDeleteParam,
      },
    })

    enabler.grantPrincipal.addToPrincipalPolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
      actions: ['inspector2:ListAccountPermissions'],
      resources: [
        Stack.of(this).formatArn({
          service: 'inspector2',
          resource: '/accountpermissions',
          arnFormat: ArnFormat.SLASH_RESOURCE_NAME,
          resourceName: 'list',
        }),
      ],
    }));
  }
}
```

Make sure to activate AWS inspector from the console to create the service-linked role.

Comment: A custom resource is not what I was looking for, but it seems to be the only solution, therefore the correct answer. Thanks! :)